# How to change the background image with react-motion and loop through a bunch of images?

Tags: reactjs, react-motion

I am using react-motion to loop through a bunch of images. I'm trying to make the background change programmatically after a certain amount of time.

Comment: I'm trying to know if it can be done with react-motion, I have 3 background images and I'm trying to loop through them with a cross fade animation.

Answer (score 0):

The component render should be something like this. Motion and spring are from 'react-motion' package. Checkout the [code for the photo demo](https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion/blob/master/demos/demo4-photo-gallery/Demo.jsx) for more details.

```
<Motion style={{height: spring(currHeight), width: spring(currWidth)}}>
  {container =>
    <div className="demo4-inner" style={container}>
      {configs.map((style, i) =>
        <Motion key={i} style={style}>
          {style =>
            <img className="demo4-photo" src={`./${i}.jpg`} style={style} />
          }
        </Motion>
      )}
    </div>
  }
</Motion>
```